# Enable Mysites for FBA users in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How does one enable Mysites for FBA users on sharepoint 2010?

I've gone through the process for enabling claims authentication and my forms based users can login but I want to also grant them the ability to create mysites, from what I've seen online this was possible to do with a bit of extra configuration in 2007, but I have yet to find a resource on how to do it in 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the following article

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010setup/thread/335c37ee-4972-4a89-b66b-3ea90d60c246/